# Lack of Hot water

Tags: plumbing

I have a 40 Gallon electric hot water heater that goes to a shower by the swimming pool of the fitness center. I get complaints of the hot water running out. the previous Facilities Director said it wasn't a problem when he was here. I tested both heating elements for continuity and both rang out fine. Could sediment be the issue? its not the T-stat either because both elements had the proper voltage.

Comment: When it "runs out" of hot water, do you still get hot water at other fixtures?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but did you check to make sure no one has messed with the heat setting on the heater? It will have knob of some sort which allows you to adjust how hot it keeps the water in the tank.

Comment: Yea, when my mother in law visited our house she complained of the same thing, so I raised the temperature knob. Of course by code in my state at least the hot water must be coming out at a certain temperature.

Comment: 40 gallons isn't that much, if it gets constant/frequent use by people that like hot showers. It sounds like it's plain running out of hot water, in which case you'd need either a larger tank or more powerful heater.

Answer (score 2):

There are two elements in electric water heaters, upper and lower. Sounds like one of them is burned out.

Comment: Or full of crud. Continuity doesn't mean it still works; just that it's still in one piece.